# Merging 2 JSON Arrays with different keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, merge

I have two JSON arrays with slightly different keys.

My first JSON has `id`, `name` and `title`.
My second JSON has `id`, `title`, `forename`, `name` and `company`.

So am I able to merge these two arrays, that every object has the same keys but some of them are possibly empty?

Two sample datas:

```
{ "id": 482136, "name": "Not a real company", "anrede": "Firma" }


{ "id": 483958, "titel": "", "anrede": "Herr", "vorname": "Muster", "name": "Mister", "firma": "gmbh", "firmaid": 1111111 }
```

And this should be my result:

```
[{ "id": 482136, "name": "Not a real company", "anrede": "Firma" ,"titel":"","vorname":"","firma":"","firmaid":""},{ "id": 483958, "titel": "", "anrede": "Herr", "vorname": "Gerry", "name": "Example", "firma": "example Company", "firmaid": 483955 }]
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you got so far?

Comment: I tried concatting them by json1.concat(json2), but this just adds the 2nd JSON objects to the 1st JSON.

Comment: Please provide at least an example, showing two input objects and the result you want to obtain.

Comment: do the objects share the same `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two JSON arrays with slightly different keys.

Note that these are actually *objects*, not *arrays*.

Use [**for … in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over each property in each object, assigning an empty string to missing properties in the other object:

```js
var j1={ "id": 482136, "name": "Not a real company", "anrede": "Firma" },
    j2={ "id": 483958, "titel": "", "anrede": "Herr", "vorname": "Pascal", "name": "Ackermann", "firma": "das druckhaus beineke dickmanns gmbh", "firmaid": 483955 };

for(var key in j1) {
  if(!j2[key]) j2[key]= '';
};

for(var key in j2) {
  if(!j1[key]) j1[key]= '';
};

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML= JSON.stringify(j1,null,2)+'\n'+JSON.stringify(j2,null,2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for your easy answer.
Oh yes, sorry my mistake. These both are objects. But I have 2 arrays with a huge amount(~ 2300) of objects.

Comment: Arrays are a *type* of object, but they have ordered index properties (0, 1, 2, 3) rather than unordered keys ("id", "name", "anrede").

Comment: Is this also possible to do if j1 or j2 are just a part of each an array?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: are the keys always `id`, `title`, `forename`, `name` and `company`? if so than i would suggest, with huge amount of data, a different approach.

Comment: I already did it dirty, adding all the missing properties to my smaller array.

       `for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++)
        {
            if (!companies[i].hasOwnProperty('vorname')) {
                companies[i].vorname = "";
                companies[i].titel = "";
                companies[i].firma = "";
                companies[i].firmaid = "";
            }
            
        }`